# Defining variable inside a tag attribute for JSF template

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to do in my template something like:

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="<ui:insert name="pagepermission"></ui:insert>">
```

And then optionally define the `pagepermission` in each page?

---

**EDIT**

So I need to write the following in my `template.xhtml`:

```
<shiro:hasPermission name="my string">
```

Where "`my string`" is defined in any page `X.xhtml` that uses the template. Writing a variable in my template coming from `X.xhtml` works fine if I `define` a variable `var` in page `X.xthml` and I just use:

```
<ui:insert name="var"></ui:insert>
```

in the template. However, since I need to write that variable **inside** an attribute (i.e. inside `<shiro:hasPermission name="**HERE**">`, then JSF complains.

Comment: ??? JSF has EL for this... `<shiro:hasPermission name="#{pagepermission}">

Comment: But pagepermission is defined in each page. I get null in the template if I use EL

Comment: Then you have to reformulate your question since it seems I fail to understand it.

Comment: I have made it as clear as possible in my edit....

Answer (score 0):

You could use wrap the content within some container, then use the `rendered` attribute:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{hasPermission}">
    <ui:insert name="pagepermission" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

For even better reuse, you could create your own custom component. See [JSF 2 fu, Part 2: Templating and composite components](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2fu2/index.html)

Comment: I cannot set a panelGroup inside the shiro:hasPemission "name" attribute.. Or I am not understanding your proposed solution